# Проблема с одновременными запросами на телеграмм бота

Tags: java, многопоточность, telegram-bot

Здравствуйте. Создал телеграмм бота на библиотеки rubenlagus/TelegramBots(Java).
Но есть одна проблема. Этим ботом, по сути, нормально может пользоваться только один человек в один момент времени. Как сделать многопоточность чтобы на одного юзера был 1 поток?

Comment: С чего вы решили, что только один человек может пользоваться? Или у вас там что-то специфичное?

Comment: @iksuy Ну у меня там для каждого человека выдает задание последовательно по итератору. И иногда на реквест одного человека выдает респонс другого человека.Если 10+ человек одновременно,то это происходит часто:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал примерно так: 
Создаем пул, и на каждый новый значимый апдейт посылаем все действия в новый поток.

---

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

---

```
@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
        Message message = update.getMessage();
        if (message.getText().equals("/start") || message.getText().equals("/start@" + getBotUsername())) {
            executorService.submit(() -> startUser(update.getMessage()));
        } else if (message.getText().equals("/cancel") || message.getText().equals("/cancel@" + getBotUsername())) {
            executorService.submit(() -> cancelOperation(message));
        } else if (message.getText().equals(ADD_NEW_SERIAL)) {
            executorService.submit(() -> startAddNewSerial(message));
        } else if (message.getText().equals(LIST_SERIALS)) {
            executorService.submit(() -> showSerialCategories(message));
        } else {
            executorService.submit(() -> checkUserStep(message));
        }
    } else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
        executorService.submit(() -> checkUserCallback(update.getCallbackQuery()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Запилил,помогло.